# Multiple ajax pagination in cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, pagination, cakephp-1.3

My problem is:

In controller:

$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array($cond_review),'limit' => 3); 
$result1 = $this->paginate('Model1');

$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array($condUser),'limit' => 2);
$result2 = $this->paginate('Model2');

```
if($this->Session->read('tab_item') == 'visit'){
            if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
                {
                        $this->layout = "";
                        $this->render('/elements/review_detail_visit_ajax');
                        return;
                }
            }else if($this->Session->read('tab_item') == 'review'){

                    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
                        {
                            $this->layout = "";
                            $this->render('/elements/friend_review_listing_ajax');
                            return;
                        }

            }
```

MOdel:

```
function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {

     $cod = implode(" AND ", $conditions);
    $recursive = -1;
    //$group = $fields = array('week', 'away_team_id', 'home_team_id');
     return $this->find('all', compact('conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'page', 'recursive', 'group'));
}

/**
 * Overridden paginateCount method
 */
function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {
    $cod = implode(" AND ", $conditions);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE 1=1 AND ".$cod;
    $this->recursive = $recursive;
    $results = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($results);
    return $num ;
}
```

here my problem is that 2 result array $result1 and $result2 have different number of data. but always it return same number of pages and limit also same.

how to solve this problem?